# Windows Essentials 2012 Email

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

Just a quick question that I can't seem to find any information on.

I understand that SBS 2011 included Exchange, and that the SBS model is no longer being made (moved to Windows Server Essentials 2012).

Does WSE2012 include Exchange the same way that SBS2011 did?

Comment: All I can find in the FAQ's about 2012 WSE is that is allows "collaboration with Office 365"... yeah...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 Essentials is the replacement for the Windows Small Business Server product line and does not include any entitlement to use Exchange. Quoting Microsoft's [Windows Server 2012 Essentials Benefits](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server-essentials/benefits.aspx) document:

> In previous versions, Windows Small Business Server Standard included
>   Exchange Server as a component product, which added expense and
>   complexity for customers who wished to leverage cloud-based messaging
>   and collaboration services.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012/2012 R2/2016 Essentials does not include Exchange Server. Office 365 would be recommended as there is Office 365 Integration Module on the Essentials Server.

For your reference more information can be found in "[Email Options Supported by Windows Server 2012 Essentials](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2012/07/26/email-options-supported-by-windows-server-2012-essentials/)".